# Update GUI components after loading settings JAVA

Tags: java, user-interface, combobox, preferences, jslider

I have an application with a GUI with sliders and comboboxes mainly. I use the sliders and combos to change values and parameters in various classes in the project. I'm trying to implement the possibility to save and load this parameters and I have done so using the preferences API.
I can save and load parameters, but when I load them I can see the changes in values, so that works, but the GUI does not update to reflect those new values. is there a way to tell the GUI to do so?

For instance I have a frequency slider that changes the frequency value in an oscillator. If I change the value with the slider, save it, change the value of the slider again and then load the saved value, I can hear it has changed but the slider didn't move.(makes sense as I haven't told it too). Can I bind the position of the slider with that frequency value somehow?

gui

```
    //OSC1 slider
    JSlider Osc1FreqSlider = new JSlider(SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL, MIN_OSC_FREQ, MAX_OSC_FREQ, NOTE_A_FREQ);
    Osc1FreqSlider.setOpaque(false);
    Osc1FreqSlider.setMajorTickSpacing(50000);
    Osc1FreqSlider.setMinorTickSpacing(50);

Osc1FreqSlider.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
            JSlider source = (JSlider) e.getSource();
            settings.setOsc1Freq((float)source.getValue()/100);

        }
    });
```

settings class

```
public void setOsc1Freq(float freq) {
    m_Osc1Freq = freq;
}
```

Comment: Yes there's a way, but its implementation will depend completely on your code.

Comment: ok, so slider moves, calls a set method in a singleton class that holds the value.
when i save i get the value with the get method, when i load i set it with the set method in that singleton class
If you tell me what details might help you I'll gladly tell you all I can. I appreciate the help :)

Comment: Please consider posting pertinent code, a [mcve], with your question.

Answer (score 0):

After `setOsc1Freq( freq )` you have to do `jSlider.setValue( freq )`.

The way I do this in my own projects is that I never use free-standing primitive values like `float freq`; instead, I have an observable class with a getter and a setter, which issues an event when the value changes, and then I wrap every single one of my controls in another class which knows how to interact with such an observable.  So, every time the value of the control changes, the value in the observable changes too, but also, every time my program changes the value of the observable, the control also takes notice and updates itself too.

I would think that it is practically impossible to write any kind of gui without this functionality, but apparently I seem to be contradicted by the existence of a myriad of gui frameworks out there that do not support this and force you to re-invent.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, could you give me a couple more details on the way you work with guis please? :)

Comment: Sorry Otenko, but that would be too broad, I would have to write a dissertation and publish code that is not fit for publishing.  But you can check out the "observable" pattern.  Essentially, there is nothing that says that only gui controls can be observables; you can make your application logic also consist of observables, and then you can bind the two.

Comment: ok cool I have to dig out my design pattern book and have a look :) thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

I solved my problem by splitting components declaration, moving them to another singleton class, creating accessor methods and then in the gui class I assigned the variables to the getters.